# Popover on Bootstrap model not working with data-toggle"table"

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have made one modal and in that modal I have used bootstrap table sorting plugin from [Bootstrap Table](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/index.html) please see Jsfiddle below for my code. In my modal you will find two tables in the modal one with Bootstrap Table plugin and second without it. The problem I am getting is on popover. Please click on right chevron which is a popover with tabs. The first table doesn't show popover and the bottom one works fine if I `remove data-toggle="table"` from the table. Do you have a solution for this?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fsnj7qg3/2/)

Answer (score 0):

In your first **popover** that isn't firing you have `<a class="btn" id="btnPopover" href="#">` and it should be `<a class="btn btnPopover" href="#">` which is what your JS is specifying.

Comment: Thanks it solve the issue i didn't see that i have used ID rather then class thanks for the answer

Comment: You're welcome. If everything worked please mark the question as answered.  Thanks!